# try/except doesn't give an error message for str() to prevent numbers

Tags: string, python-2.7, try-except

This following temple is working for int() or float(), but it is not working for str(). 
My expectation is to come up with the warning message : 'Please enter an string', but it didn't work. Do you have an idea ?

```
inp = raw_input("Enter a word") # for instance number =123
try :
    i = str(inp)

except :

    print 'Please enter a str'
```

---

**As a recommend:**

Wroking : No

```
inp=raw_input("enter a string")
if not isintance(inp, str):
    print "it is not a string!")
else :
    print " you done!"
```

Working : Yes

```
inp = 123
if not isintance(inp, str):
    print "it is not a string!")
else:
    print " you done!"
```

--> This path is not working with raw_input() :P
it ia really strange ..

@Woly

Thank you very much .. You path is working very well! :D

Comment: I really don't understand why you'd expect `str(number)` to raise an exception here. Neither `float(number)` or `int(number)` do so either, despite your saying otherwise, so perhaps you should explain what you're doing a bit more.

Comment: i reformed to program for u to understand me better. 
my expectation to take a warning when user enter any number.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent an input that contains *any* digits, or just inputs that are *all* digits?

Comment: i'm trying to prevent the user to give me any number as a input ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want that check for data type, `type(number)`.
If you ask for user input, the result shoud be `<type 'str'>` in python2 or `<class 'str'>` in python3 so you do not need to convert.

```
inp = raw_input("Enter a word") # for instance number =123
try :
   i = str(inp)
   print i
except :
   # This will never happen

   print 'Please enter a str'
```

**Edit**:
You need to check if the input is not a digit.

```
inp = raw_input("Enter a word") # for instance number =123

if not inp.isdigit():
    print inp
else:
    print 'Please enter a str'
```

Comment: i wish to prevent user to enter any number when i ask them "enter the key word or bla bla "
"number = 123 " is just a sample input for the program ..

Comment: Use `int()` if you want to get integers from user or `float()` to get floats.`str(input()) should not raise an exception error`.

Comment: the logic which i did in that code is working very well for float or integer number like following code :
try :
    i = float(inp)
except:
    print "please enter a number"

However this path doesn't work for str()

Comment: how can take a warning like "only strings please when the user type any number ?

Comment: So you want to check if an input contains a digit.

Comment: yes.. ! but my program must let only strings --of course string could include numbers like "micheal23"

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to try-except:

```
inp=input("enter a string: ")
if not isinstance(inp, str):
    print 'Please enter a str'
```

To use try-except, you could do:

```
inp=input("enter a string: ")
try:
    if not isinstance(inp, str): raise
except: 
    print 'Please enter a str'
```

Examples:

```
enter a string: 1
Please enter a str

enter a string: 1.1
Please enter a str

enter a string: 'yes'
<no output here>
```

Edit: Because the purpose is to prevent any number input, regex would work well:

```
import re
inp=raw_input("enter a string: ")
if re.findall('[0-9]', inp):
    print 'Please enter a str'
else:
    print " you done!"
```

Comment: Hi,
but it is not working when i use "raw_input("Enter a string")

isn't it strange?

Comment: The problem is with raw_input, which always return a string; Try use input like: input("enter a string"). If you enter 1, then it's an integer; if 1.1, then it's float; if 'yes', then it's string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working the way you expect because `raw_input` *always returns a string*.

The try/except template you're using works when you're asking for a number because you're converting a string the user entered into an `int` or `float` and the `int` and `float` constructors will raise an exception if they are passed a string that doesn't correspond to their type. That doesn't work with `str` because there's no conversion required. Calling `str` on something that is already a string will never fail.

If you want to reject certain strings based on their *content* rather than their type, you will need to do something else. For instance, `str.isalpha` will return `True` if all the characters in a string are alphabetical.

Comment: That's really good explanation! i didn't know before this function :"isalpha()"
So i can take a warning if "raw_input / str " include any character except alphabet .. 
thank you very much! :D